# DevExtrem Angular - DataGrid - How to use raw template with server side data processing

Tags: angular, devextreme, devextreme-angular

I am integrating the DevExtrem datagrid with Angular and Server side processing : https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/Data_Binding/Specify_a_Data_Source/Custom_Data_Sources/

I would like to know if it is possible de have a custom raw template with server side processing ?
The API will return an object "Currency" -> {"Symbol","Code"} but the actual data source display "Object" in the raw, so I need to tell to the datagrid to display in the row currency.code .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using dxTemplate =

```
<dx-data-grid
                [dataSource]="customDataSource"
                dataRowTemplate="dataRowTemplateName"
            >
                <ng-container *dxTemplate="let test of 'dataRowTemplateName'">
                    <tr class="main-row">
                        <td>{{ test.data.id }}</td>
                        <td>{{ test.data.base_price }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </ng-container>
```